# Incorrect path returned for saved photo Cordova android 11

Tags: android, cordova

Launch the camera to capture a photo; take the photo; examine the opject returned. The fullPath property of the returned object is something like file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1652174370741.jpg, while the image file is actually saved to something like file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20220510_101151.jpg.

The video capture works fine. The fullPath property of the returned object is like file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20220510_101151.mp4, and that's the actual path to the saved file.

At least one other person has mentioned a permissions problem causing problems with accessing the file from the information returned. I don't believe this is anything to do with permissions, given that the image file actually saves, and it works fine for video files.